# Music Recommander using Implicit Library

Tags: machine-learning, python, recommender-system

I want to build a music recommender predicting the number of times a user will listen to a song. I am using the [Implicit](https://github.com/benfred/implicit) library and following this close example :
https://github.com/benfred/implicit/blob/main/examples/tutorial_lastfm.ipynb

I wanted to know how can I predict the number of plays for a given user for a specific song, all I can see there and in the documentation is to recommend songs to a given user with scores of proximity but without giving the actual prediction

Comment: Generally, a recommendation system recommends *what* to offer, not how many times.  Predicting a numeric quantity e.g. # of times a song is played is a regression problem.

Comment: I agree but fitting a regression model on a simple dataset with only user, item, and weight will not catch a strong correlation ( I think so no ? ) 
The Advantage there is using CF to predict, also ALS is trying to reduce the dimension of the matrix for the weight so I was thinking maybe trying to reconstruct a predicted matrix with a dot product of the result of the ALS algorithm ?

Trying to fit a regression model with the score for each user to another item and to each user can help me predicting this score ?

Comment: I am just stating that general recommendation system will not do the job; how to build the regression model is a separate topic. And of course you can craft a model with the "score for each user to another item" as feature, but nevertheless it would be a regression model.